# Phonegap google maps api query not working

Tags: android, google-maps, phonegap

I am developing a simple android app using phonegap that sends a google maps geocoding api request with lat,lan location and returns an address. 
When working using my desktop, everything works fine! 
Once I build the app using the adobe phonegap cloud builder, it does not work. in addition, I am unable to debug as nothing is presented on the app. it simply shows an empty value.

Could this be a CORS issue? HTTPS? Some issue using a mobile user-agent for google maps requests? I am unsure. appreciate any help!

this is my code:

```
function maps_api(latlng){
    var divdata = $('div#data');
    divdata.text('cleared');
    updateStatus('Starting google api: ');
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           updateStatus(this.responseText);
           var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var divdata = $('div#data');
                  divdata.text(myArr["results"][0]["formatted_address"]);

        }
        else
        {
            updateStatus(this.responseText);
            var divdata = $('div#data');
            divdata.text(xhttp.statusText);

        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlng + "&key=myprivatekey", true);
    xhttp.send();



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by installing the whitelist-plugin and allowing communication to google maps server